# vim formatting on github

Tags: github, vim

Ever since I started using `vim`, some of my files look vastly different on a github view as far as indentation goes. It's the weirdest behavior. I'll open the file in both `vim` and `atom` and all the indentations look fine, as soon as i open that same file in github the formatting is all wonky.

Here are some screen shots:

#### Code in vim:

[image]

#### Code in atom:

[image]

#### Code on github:

[image]

Everything I've seen in my google searches about indentation are issues with various plugins and nothing to with this. Any ideas why this is happening? If it helps here's my `.vimrc` file:

```
syntax on
set number
set hlsearch
set showcmd
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set splitright
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set iskeyword-=_
set autoindent
set smartindent
set scrolloff=999
set syntax=markdown

noremap <C-h> <C-w>h
noremap <C-j> <C-w>j
noremap <C-k> <C-w>k
noremap <C-l> <C-w>l
noremap <C-t> gt

au BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown
```

Comment: Try `set expandtab` for new files, add `?ts=2` to the github URLs of the existing files.

Comment: great! this worked! if you want to answer I'll give you the check. thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file named .editorconfig in your github repo with this contents:

```
[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
```

Comment: hmm, this isn't fixing the files already in the repo, do i need to configure this in some way? it does work when i add the querystring to the url

Comment: @AndrewKim Sorry, edited the file contents. It should work with existing files too. You can use a specific file extension instead of `[*]`. e.g. `[*.java]`